# Question about intersections of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be subspaces of a vector space with $A \cap B=0$. I am wondering if it is always true that $(A+B) \cap C=(A \cap(B+C))+(B \cap C)$. If it is not true in general, are there reasonable conditions that would make it true?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is true: $(A\cup(B+C)) + (B \cup C) = A \cup B + A \cup C + B \cup C = A \cup C + B \cup C = (A+B) \cup C$

Answer (score 0):

This isn't true.  For instance, let the ambient vector space be $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $A$ spanned by $(1,0)$, $B$ spanned by $(0,1)$, and $C$ spanned by $(1,1)$.  Then $(A+B)\cap C=C$ but $(A\cap(B+C))+(B\cap C)=A$. I don't know what kind of conditions you would be hoping for that would make it true; it's true somewhat trivially, for instance, if $C$ is contained in either $A$ or $B$, or if $C$ contains $A+B$.